# Debezium Interrupted while emitting initial DROP TABLE events

Tags: java, debezium

I'm trying to set up Debezium engine with MariaDB and ActiveMQ. I'm using Quarkus framework. I'm following the official documentation (https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/development/engine.html). When I start the engine I get the following error:

```
2021-05-03 10:05:53,184 INFO  [io.deb.pip.sou.AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource] (debezium-mysqlconnector-my-app-connector-change-event-source-coordinator) Snapshot - Final stage
2021-05-03 10:05:53,184 WARN  [io.deb.pip.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator] (debezium-mysqlconnector-my-app-connector-change-event-source-coordinator) Change event source executor was interrupted: java.lang.InterruptedException: Interrupted while emitting initial DROP TABLE events
```

Not really sure why this happens and so far I've not been able to track down the source of the problem so any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by deleting the file configured with the property `offset.storage.file.filename`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Run the engine asynchronously ...
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.execute(engine);

// Do something else or wait for a signal or an event
```

Make sure DO wait something, or the connector thread will be terminated by the main thread, and you will get a message like "Snapshot was interrupted before completion".